# Setuptools include script in source package

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

I'm using setuptool to make python packages, and I want some extra scripts included in any source packages generated i.e. `ez_setup.py` to install setuptools if its not already installed.

I can only find how to include files in the distribution, which I don't want as the files I want to include are only required for the running setup.py with python to install/build the package.

How can I set them to be only included in the source packages, and not actually installed on the users system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem is a lot of the documentation is poorly worded the **MANIFEST only applies** to the **source packages**, hence files listed in MANIFEST.in will be added to the MANIFEST, and included in the **source package**.

see https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html, setup tools is a fork of distutils.

P.S. Don't worry that some of the setup tools documentation makes it sound like this adds files to the egg manifest it doesn't, only the source distribution is affected.